# Regexp matching group not working on objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'm trying to get from this string: 5556007503140005
Two strings. "555600750314" and "0005"

I'm Using the regexp `^([a-z0-9]*)([0-9]{4})$`that works fine on the regexp tools, but when i use this on my code I only get 1 match.

this is the code

```
-(NSDictionary *)parse_barcode:(NSString *)barcode {
    NSString *regexp = @"^([a-z0-9]*)([0-9]{4})$";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",regexp];

    if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:barcode]) {
        NSError *error;

        NSRegularExpression *regular_exp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexp options:0 error:&error];

        NSArray *matches = [regular_exp matchesInString:barcode options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [barcode length])];

        for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
            NSLog(@"match %@ :%@",[barcode substringWithRange:[match range]], match);
        }

    }
    return nil;
}
```

But the match is always the entire string (Barcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the right match, you are just not printing them correctly. You need to use `numberOfRanges` to get the individual *groups* (i.e. sections enclosed in parentheses), and then call `rangeAtIndex:` for each group, like this:

```
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != match.numberOfRanges ; i++) {
        NSLog(@"match %d - %@ :%@", i, [barcode substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:i]], match);
    }
}
```